# Glitch in R-Stata communication

Tags: r, stata

I am attempting to use the *community-contributed* command `rcall` in Stata.

I wish to begin by bringing vectors and/or variables from Stata to R. My vector `X` is also a matrix `X`. When I use the code below to send R my variable `X`:

```
rcall: Y = st.var(X)
```

I get the following error:

> too many numeric literals

If instead I use the code below, to send R my matrix `X`:

```
rcall: Y = st.matrix(X)
```

I get the error below:

> Y not found

Though occasionally I'm pretty sure I've gotten the numeric literals error for this matrix attempt.

In addition, in neither case does it help if I replace `=` with `<-`.

I have a feeling I'm using this command quite wrong, but I *am* following the Stata help code. So far, I have been unable to find any further examples of `rcall` online.

Any help would be appreciated!

Note that this question has been cross-posted (a few days ago, with no reply) on [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1445761-rcall-error-too-many-numeric-literals).

Comment: Something is not installed correctly. For me first doing `matrix A = (1,2\3,4)` and next `rcall: Y <- st.matrix(A)` works fine. Then if i type `rcall: Y` lists the matrix in the Stata results window.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I think you are right about installation. Or rather, it seems that something is not "cleared" properly. Previously, such little examples worked for me. (I did all the help file examples fine, before beginning my work work.) But at the moment, after defining matrix A as above, and then typing `rcall: Y <- st.matrix(A)`, I get the error `Ya not found`.  `Ya` is a matrix from a previous script, but I have no idea why Stata is still remembering it, or what that error means. I have, of course, shut Stata down between that previous script and now. Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: It might also be the R session that `rcall` uses. Try typing `rcall clear` from Stata's command prompt.

Comment: Oh wow... this works! I feel silly, but also shocked that I couldn't find this online anywhere. However... sadly, it looks like rcall might not be an option for me, after all. I tried to load a matrix that is 1,000 by 100, and apparently it's too large, even at max memory size. (The error says: macro substitution results in line that is too long. The line resulting from substituting macros would be longer than allowed.  The maximum allowed length is 645,216 characters, which is calculated on the basis of set maxvar.)

Comment: If rcall is not an option, do you happen to know of another way to run R script via Stata, then import a list of strings back into Stata as a macro? Basically, I just want to run Lasso in R, from Stata, and then import the names of the subset variables back as a macro. The vanilla option allows me to run R from Stata, but not to bring results back into Stata.

Comment: From the sound of it, it looks you have two other _separate_ problems: a) loading a large matrix and b) getting the variable names back in a local macro from R. Your other problems should be posted as separate questions so they can be easily answered and preserved for future readers with the same problems.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'll post a separate thread, as suggested. And yes, checked your answer, which definitely solved the first problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems like these usually result either from something not installed correctly, ***or*** the software in question starts encountering memory leaks and becomes unstable because of continuous usage.

After installing `rcall`, the following works for me:

```
matrix A = (1,2\3,4)

rcall: Y <- st.matrix(A) 
rcall: Y

   c1 c2
r1  1  2
r2  3  4
```

So assuming `rcall` is correctly installed, then the R session that it uses may have been corrupted.

Try typing from Stata's command prompt:

```
rcall clear
```

This will erase the R session's memory and history.